# How to properly use .dropLast()

Tags: swift

So this question is a just a smaller portion of a bigger problem. But it all boils down to my misunderstanding of this function..

Given my function:

```
    func diamond(_ size: Int) -> String {
         var diamonds = ""
         for diamond in 0...size {
             if diamond % 2 == 1 || diamond == 1 {
                  diamonds.append(String(repeating: "*", count: diamond))
                  diamonds.append("\n")
    }
  }
    print(diamonds)
    print("This should print one row less but doesn't\n", diamonds.dropLast())
    diamonds = diamonds + diamonds.dropLast().reversed()
    return diamonds
}

diamond(5)
```

The expected output for `diamond(5)` should be =

```
*
***
*****
***
*
```

But current output is:

```
*
***
*****
***** //<-- Doubled
***
*
```

How am I misusing dropLast? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here  `diamonds.append("\n")`
You are adding a new line at the last and you are dropping last. It means you are dropping `"\n"` instead of `*`.

Also, you have to drop the character for size `size` . The reason is while you printing you have already printing and covering `*****` max size starts at the first time so no need this in `reversed()`

So, your final function is

```
func diamond(_ size: Int) -> String {
    var diamonds = ""
    for diamond in 0...size {
        if diamond % 2 == 1 || diamond == 1 {
            if diamond != 1 {
                diamonds.append("\n")
            }
            diamonds.append(String(repeating: "*", count: diamond))
        }
    }
    diamonds = diamonds + diamonds.dropLast(size).reversed()
    return diamonds
}
```

Test:

```
// Inputs
print("============diamond(3)================")
print(diamond(3))
print("============diamond(5)================")
print(diamond(5))
print("============diamond(7)================")
print(diamond(7))


// Outputs
============diamond(3)================
    *
    ***
    *
    ============diamond(5)================
    *
    ***
    *****
    ***
    *
    ============diamond(7)================
    *
    ***
    *****
    *******
    *****
    ***
    *
```